# Как правильно реализовать зажатие View

Tags: java, android

Пользователь должен выбрать несколько вариантов ответа.

Как правильно это реализовать?
Сделать кнопки? Сделать TextView?
Что посоветуете?

Comment: checkbox специально для этого